# get double value on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, double

I want to output time of query in seconds on JSP.
in struts Action class I do next

```
long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
/////////////////////////////////////
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
double timeOfQuery = (end - begin)/1000;
request.setAttribute(TIME_OF_QUERY, timeOfQuery);
```

And on JSP I try to get time query in seconds
different ways

```
Time of Query: ${timeOfQuery}
<br/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${timeOfQuery}" minFractionDigits="3"/>
sec<br />
```

but in both of case I get value as 3.0 for ${timeOfQuery}.
And 3.000 in case  I want to get not rounded value. But can't find the way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast it to double first, otherwise result will be in long format.

```
double timeOfQuery = (double)(end - begin)/1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use,

double timeOfQuery = (end - begin)/1000.00;